# How to create a heat map with the number of repetition inside a certain range value

Tags: r, histogram, heatmap

I have a dataset that looks like this one, with month (mese) in one column and the corresponding value in the other column and I'm trying to create a heatmap with the month(s) on the x axis, different "intervals" on the y axis (e.g. from 0 to 10, 10 to 20, 20 to 30 etc.) and the number of times a certain range of value repeats itself inside the month for each range. 
I tried to use the cut function for both the x and the y axis in order to create a number of ranges of values, then putting everything into a table and plotting it with this code

```
 x_c <- cut(x, 12)
 y_c <- cut(y, 50)
 z <- table(x_c, y_c)
 image2D(z=z, border="black")
```

but it doesn't seem to work: the scale is always from 0 to 1 (and i need the actual values)... is there an easier solution?

[image: dataset]

---

Essentially, I need the end result to look something like this (sorry for my very poor paint skills): i.e. the level of sulphate is higher during the winter than the summer and the majority of the data follow a "curve" that reflect this tendency
[image: example in paint]

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example?

Comment: I was not able to find  real example, I tried to explain better with a quick example i draw in paint

Comment: It's not a matter of explaining, it's for others to be able to run your example and test a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `geom_bin2d` from `ggplot2`. You can define the number of bins:

```
ggplot(data, aes(mese, nnso4)) + 
geom_bin2d(bins=c(12,50)) + 
scale_fill_gradient(low="yellow", high="red")
```

You can change the fill scale, for instance `viridis` package has some options.